# Google API oauth2 token expires?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a problem with google api and oauth2 token.

There is an app which allows to synchronize contacts / calendar with your google account by oauth2 token.

When first time user wants to connect with his google account, he needs to grant access , then app is receiving code/token which is saved and will be used for offline synchronization later.

```
function getClient($app) 
{       
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig("path_to_secret.json");

    switch($app)
    {
        case 'contacts':
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Script::WWW_GOOGLE_COM_M8_FEEDS);
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_People::USERINFO_EMAIL);
        break;

        case 'calendar':
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
        break;

        default:
        throw new Exception('API Callback not defined in setup');
    }

    $client->setAccessType('offline'); // offline access
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_APP_URL . $app.'/callback.php');
    return $client;
}
```

(there are different tokens for contacts and calendar)

The synchronization script:

```
...
try
{
    $client = getClient('calendar');
    $client->setAccessToken(unserialize($accessToken));
    $http = $client->authorize();

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    ...
}
```

$accessToken is a serialized string like:

```
a:5:{s:12:"access_token";s:131:"******token_here********";s:10:"token_type";s:6:"Bearer";s:10:"expires_in";i:3598;s:8:"id_token";s:902:"***id_token****";s:7:"created";i:1505178047;}
```

**This is working for first time and couple more times but after some time(hours) there is an error:**

> Error: {"error": {  "errors": [   {    "domain": "global",    "reason": "authError",    "message": "Invalid Credentials",    "locationType": "header",    "location": "Authorization"   }  ],  "code": 401,  "message": "Invalid Credentials" }}

What I am doing wrong?

What is interesting that for contacts synchronization works fine all the time (access token has the same attributes as in calendar synchronization )

Comment: You probably need a refresh token

Comment: What version of Google API Client do you use?

Comment: It's version 2.0

Comment: I didn't get refresh token with access token..and in contacts synchronization I also don't have refresh token and it is working fine all the time.. Is it working different for Google Calendar ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Google API Client may have an internal mechanism which is automatically refreshing `access_token`, if it's needed. When you authorizing any user by code – you might have `refresh_token`, which allows you to get new `access_token`, when last is expired (just with access type == 'offline'). What changes did you make before you get this error?

Comment: I wasn't changing anything. It never worked for long time than just for first couple of hours. For contact synchronization is almost equally the same code and its working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, propably solved - refresh_token is provided for the first time only, so when I was testing it more times then I didn't get refresh token. 
When I revoked access in https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/permissions and connected again then I received also refresh token. I assume now it will work properly